# How to find a best fit circle/ellipse using R?

Tags: r, best-fit-curve

I've been reading about a few methods to fit a circle to data (like [this](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/kerryj/kjones/circles.pdf)). I would like to see how the methods work on real data and thought of using R for this. I tried searching rseek for packages that can help with this but came up with nothing useful.

So, are there packages that help to easily compute the best fit circle for a given data set (similar to how `lm()` will fit a linear model to a data set)? Otherwise, how might one perform such a task in R?

Comment: have a look at this article 
http://www.onthelambda.com/2014/07/24/interactive-visualization-of-non-linear-logistic-regression-decision-boundaries-with-shiny/

And this shiny app

https://tonyfischetti.shinyapps.io/InteractiveLogisticRegression/

Comment: The methods in the paper you cite don't look too hard to implement. There's only ever three parameters (x,y,r) and the method with closed-form solutions don't even need optimisation. Have a go programming them up, you'll learn a lot of R skills. Make a package...

Comment: Since ellipses are not single-valued, you can't use linear (or even nonlinear) fit tools, as those almost exclusively expect single-valued functions.  Thus, do what @Spacedman says.  Heck, if you don't I will just because it looks like fun :-)

Comment: Voting to reopen because I don't see that calculating a bounding ellipse really fits this question.  Even if you calculate a 50% bounding ellipse, it's not immediately clear that that will turn out to be the (least-squares,e.g.) best fit to the points themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fairly naive implementation of a function that minimises SS(a,b,r) from that paper:

```
fitSS <- function(xy,
                  a0=mean(xy[,1]),
                  b0=mean(xy[,2]),
                  r0 = mean(sqrt((xy[,1]-a0)^2 + (xy[,2]-b0)^2)),
                  ...){
    SS <- function(abr){
        sum((abr[3] - sqrt((xy[,1]-abr[1])^2 + (xy[,2]-abr[2])^2))^2)
    }
    optim(c(a0,b0,r0), SS, ...)
}
```

I've written a couple of supporting functions to generate random data on circles and to plot circles. Hence:

```
> xy = sim_circles(10)
> f = fitSS(xy)
```

The `fit$par` value is a vector of xcenter, ycenter, radius.

```
> plot(xy,asp=1,xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2))
> lines(circlexy(f$par))
```

[image: points and fitted circle]

Note it doesn't use the gradients nor does it check the error code for convergence. You can supply it with initial values or it can have a guess.

Code for plotting and generating circles follows:

```
circlexy <- function(xyr, n=180){
    theta = seq(0,2*pi,len=n)
    cbind(xyr[1] + xyr[3]*cos(theta),
          xyr[2] + xyr[3]*sin(theta)
          )
}
sim_circles <- function(n,x=0,y=0,r=1,sd=0.05){
    theta = runif(n, 0, 2*pi)
    r = r + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=sd)
    cbind(x + r*cos(theta),
          y + r*sin(theta)
      )
}
```

Comment: Hey, I thought you told the *SO* to write the package :-)

Comment: Knew I'd find it somewhere (at last) :  `plotrix::draw.circle` appears to do what your `lines(circlexy(foo))` does.

Comment: I suppose sim_circles has `runif(n. -pi, pi)` somewhere in it. Perhaps `function(n=10, radius=1, var=radius/10){angle=runif(n. -pi, pi);list(x=radius*sin(angle)+var*runif(n), y=radius*cos(angle)+var*runif(n))}`

Comment: what is the library required for 'xy = sim_circles(10)', the dataset is not available?? and how to get the radius from it

Answer (score 2):

Well, looky here: an   [R-blogger column](http://lastresortsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/09/fitting-ellipse-to-point-data.html) has written some code to fit to ellipses and circles. His code, which I won't repost here, is based on previous work done by Radim Halíř and Jan Flusser in Matlab.   His code includes (commented) the original Matlab lines for comparison.

I've peeked at a number of papers on this topic, and can only say that I'm not qualified to determine which algorithms are the most robust.  For those interested,  take a look at these papers:

http://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/sup962/gander.pdf

http://ralph.cs.cf.ac.uk/papers/Geometry/fit.pdf

http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/WSCG98.pdf

Followup edit:  I ran Spacedman's code against the linked R-code for fitting ellipses, using the same "noisy" set of 1e5 points on a circle as input.  The results are:

```
testcircle<-create.test.ellipse(Rx=200,Ry=200,Rot=.56,Noise=5.5,leng=100000)
 dim(testcircle)
[1] 100000      2

microbenchmark(fitSS(testcircle),fit.ellipse(testcircle))
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
       fitSS(testcircle) 649.98245 704.05751 731.61282 787.84212 2053.7096
 fit.ellipse(testcircle)  25.74518  33.87718  38.87143  95.23499  256.2475
 neval
   100
   100
```

For reference, the output of the two fitting functions were:

From `SSfit`, the list

```
ssfit
$par
[1] 249.9530 149.9927 200.0512

$value
[1] 185.8195

$counts
function gradient 
     134       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

From `fit.ellipse`, we get

```
ellfit
$coef
            a             b             c             d             e 
-7.121109e-01 -1.095501e-02 -7.019815e-01  3.563866e+02  2.136497e+02 
            f 
-3.195427e+04 

$center
       x        y 
249.0769 150.2326 

$major
[1] 201.7601

$minor
[1] 199.6424

$angle
[1] 0.412268
```

You can see that the elliptic equation's coefficients are near-zero for terms which "deviate" from a circle;  plotting the two results yields almost indistinguishable curves.

Answer (score 0):

To fit an ellipse, there is the `fitEllipse` function in the **PlaneGeometry** package. It uses the **fitConic** package.

```r
library(PlaneGeometry)

library(PlaneGeometry)
# the "true" ellipse: 
ell <- Ellipse$new(center = c(1, 1), rmajor = 3, rminor = 2, alpha = 25)
# We add some noise to 30 points on this ellipse:
set.seed(666L)
points <- ell$randomPoints(30, "on") + matrix(rnorm(30*2, sd = 0.2), ncol = 2)
# Now we fit an ellipse to these points:
ellFitted <- fitEllipse(points)
# let's draw all this stuff, true ellipse in blue, fitted ellipse in green:
box <- ell$boundingbox()
plot(NULL, asp = 1, xlim = box$x, ylim = box$y, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
draw(ell, border = "blue", lwd = 2)
points(points, pch = 19)
draw(ellFitted, border = "green", lwd = 2)
```

[image]